# SpringApplication.run() loads entire database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, javafx, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot, MySQL, JavaFX, client server application - No web - and had a surprising effect that although I didn't altered any entity from the UI, I got an ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException saying "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction". So I was wondering what - if not me - is updating this entity, and started to debug by switching on

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

in my property file to see what is going on between the application and the database. What I found is something that I don't understand at all:

When the application starts, right in the beginning, before any of my code is called as far as I can say, SpringApplication.run(..) is called:

```
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    springContext = SpringApplication.run(ProdMgrApp.class);
    ..
}
```

When I execute this command in the debugger - but also if don't run the application from the debugger - the application generates 563 thousand (!) lines of SQL code, basically querying the entire database -  a couple of thousands selects, over 100 updates, and about 400 inserts. Interestingly, despite the insert statements, the database content is not doubled or extended in anyway. But the integer version information for optimistic locking (@Version) is increasing. In a way it doesn't harm, but it takes a while - also without debugging statements to the console - and when the database will grow,.. this is a no-go.

What am I doing wrong?

Although I am working now a while with Spring Boot and in particular with the JPA part, I am still far away from being an expert. Let me know, should you need more information.

**EDIT**:
I debugged a bit a realized that because I am combining JavaFX and Spring Boot the startup of the application differs from "normal" setup. In a non JavaFX application the SpringApplication.run() call is located in main(). In a JavaFX application the call is located in init() - see also https://better-coding.com/javafx-spring-boot-gradle-project-setup-guide-and-test/ as a result within SpringApplication deduceMainApplicationClass() will return null. Could that be the root cause?

The trace looks like this:

```
INFO 17:00 o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting:50: Starting application on ThinkPad with PID 6664 (started by Alexander in C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\Codebase\agiletunes-codespace\agiletunes-productmanager) 
 INFO 17:00 o.s.b.SpringApplication.logStartupProfileInfo:646: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 
 INFO 17:00 o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn:126: Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode. 
 INFO 17:00 o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn:182: Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1151ms. Found 39 repository interfaces. 
 INFO 17:00 c.z.h.HikariDataSource.getConnection:110: HikariPool-1 - Starting... 
 INFO 17:00 c.z.h.HikariDataSource.getConnection:123: HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 
 INFO 17:00 o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation:31: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...] 
 INFO 17:00 o.h.Version.logVersion:46: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final} 
 INFO 17:00 o.h.c.Environment.<clinit>:213: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 
 INFO 17:00 o.h.a.c.r.j.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>:49: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final} 
DEBUG 17:00 o.h.t.BasicTypeRegistry.register:156: Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@5ffacf79 
DEBUG 17:00 o.h.t.BasicTypeRegistry.register:156: Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@5ffacf79 
DEBUG 17:00 o.h.t.BasicTypeRegistry.register:156: Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@5ffacf79 
DEBUG 17:00 o.h.t.BasicTypeRegistry.register:156: Adding type registration numeric_boolean -> org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType@4058800 
DEBUG 17:00 o.h.t.BasicTypeRegistry.register:156: Adding type registration true_false -> org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType@46bb075a 
DEBUG 17:00 o.h.t.BasicTypeRegistry.register:156: Adding type registration yes_no -> org.hibernate.type.YesNoType@7d390456 
.. more lines of registrations and ParameterValues ..
DEBUG 17:01 o.h.t.EnumType.setParameterValues:126: Using NAMED-based conversion for Enum com.agiletunes.shared.domain.risk.Risk$Severity 
DEBUG 17:01 o.h.t.EnumType.setParameterValues:126: Using NAMED-based conversion for Enum com.agiletunes.shared.domain.risk.Risk$Type 
DEBUG 17:01 o.h.t.EnumType.setParameterValues:126: Using NAMED-based conversion for Enum com.agiletunes.shared.domain.risk.Risk$Type 
TRACE 17:01 o.h.t.s.TypeConfiguration.sessionFactoryCreated:195: Handling #sessionFactoryCreated from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@25b9be87] for TypeConfiguration 
 INFO 17:01 o.s.o.j.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory:415: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
 INFO 17:01 o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted:59: Started application in 20.227 seconds (JVM running for 22.033) 
 INFO 17:01 o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.initiateService:47: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        Product as generatedAlias0 */ select
            product0_.id as id2_59_,
            product0_.goal as goal3_59_,
            product0_.identifier as identifi4_59_,
            product0_.level as level5_59_,
            product0_.parent_id as parent_25_59_,
            product0_.plannedBegin as plannedB6_59_,
            product0_.plannedEnd as plannedE7_59_,

followed by thousands lines of SQL
```

This is my property file:

```
#No JMX needed - disabling it allows for faster startup
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.main.banner-mode=off
#no web server needed
spring.main.web-application-type=none

# Properties can be queried in the code e.g. @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")   private String message;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/agiletunesdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&characterSetResults=utf-8
spring.datasource.username=YYYYYY
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX

# create db schema
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#----  Naming strategy: Use underscore instead of camel case
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#----  Prevent use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator] table-based id generator
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#----   Show sql queries send to db
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
#----   Print SQL statements spread over multiple lines for easier readibility
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#----   show parameter values in sql statements complemental to "?"
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE


#----  Switch on colors
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
logging.pattern.console=%highlight(%5p) %d{HH:mm} %C{3}.%method:%L: %msg %n
```

Comment: You are using an embedded database ?
I didnt see your mysql properties

Comment: That is definitely weird. Can you post some of those SQL statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I have a CommandLineRunner which is supposed to create test data when the database is empty. This CommandLineRunner tries to read all entities from a certain table and if nothing is returned it populates all tables. The trouble is that something is wrong with the lazy loading of the related entity. I have to investigate this and if needed I'll open a new question.